# Why bootstrap 5 position-sticky not working?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5, trying to make responsive card ads. left card. For some reason, the sticky-top won't work.

I'm trying to create a sticky sidebar on the left. The sidebar menu is inside a grid column. I'm using the sticky-top class as shown in this question, but it still doesn't work.

Here is my code:Here is my code; I am not aware of any possible collisions with sticky-top.

```
<!Docktype html>
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Selda</title>
</head>
<body class="bg-light d-flex flex-column min-vh-100" data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="8.904.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Selda</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a>
                </li>    
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Counselings</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Learning</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">About-US</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact-US</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container min-vh-100">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mb-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" style="height: 90px"></div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="d-block d-md-flex mb-3">
                        <div style="width:115px; margin-top:-75px">
                            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRDsY.png" class="rounded-circle img-thumbnail">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <span class="badge bg-success">Online</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="h5">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check text-success"></i>
                            John Sina
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-3">
            <div class="menu sticky-top">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h6 class="card-title">Plan</h6>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item p-0 align-items-center">
                            <a class="d-flex justify-content-between list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0" href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-file-pdf"></i>
                                    <span>Download PDF</span>
                                </div>
                                <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Free</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item p-0 align-items-center">
                            <a class="d-flex justify-content-between list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0" href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-photo-film"></i>
                                    <span>Download Video</span>
                                </div>
                                <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">85,000 $</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item p-0 align-items-center">
                            <a class="d-flex justify-content-between list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0" href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i>
                                    <span>Download Word</span>
                                </div>
                                <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Free</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg w-100">Payment</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">About me</h6>
                    <p>Text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">My Video</h6>
                    <video poster="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRDsY.png" controls="" class="w-100" __idm_id__="1286145">
                        <source src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/counselings/1674029169.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js  "></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `menu` div is the one I'd like to stick to the top as the user scrolls down.

Comment: You spelled `DOCTYPE` wrong. If this wasn't part of the issue, it may have caused other issues you haven't noticed yet as it may put you into quirks mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that elements only stick to their parent element, so the menu stays within the column. You should separate your page to two large columns: one for all the other rows/columns and the other for your sidebar that will stay sticked to the top. Try this (although you may have to change some padding/margins due to nested rows):

```
<div class="container min-vh-100">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mb-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12"></div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" style="height: 90px"></div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="d-block d-md-flex mb-3">
                                <div style="width:115px; margin-top:-75px">
                                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRDsY.png" class="rounded-circle img-thumbnail">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <span class="badge bg-success">Online</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <h1 class="h5">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check text-success"></i>
                                    John Sina
                                </h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h6 class="card-title">About me</h6>
                            <p>Text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h6 class="card-title">My Video</h6>
                            <video poster="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRDsY.png" controls="" class="w-100" __idm_id__="1286145">
                                <source src="http://localhost:8000/storage/videos/counselings/1674029169.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-3">
            <div class="menu sticky-top">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h6 class="card-title">Plan</h6>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item p-0 align-items-center">
                            <a class="d-flex justify-content-between list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0" href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-file-pdf"></i>
                                    <span>Download PDF</span>
                                </div>
                                <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Free</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item p-0 align-items-center">
                            <a class="d-flex justify-content-between list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0" href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-photo-film"></i>
                                    <span>Download Video</span>
                                </div>
                                <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">85,000 $</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item p-0 align-items-center">
                            <a class="d-flex justify-content-between list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0" href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i>
                                    <span>Download Word</span>
                                </div>
                                <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Free</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg w-100">Payment</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to create sticky-top?

Comment: <div class="menu sticky-top"> is in the code I posted, or do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean something else